# Creating Objects from objects ? Or am i deluded

Tags: ruby, object, new-operator

What is happening in the following code

```
A = Class.new

class << A
  def speak
    puts "Dave"
  end
end

A.speak
B = A.new
```

How is this possible what is really happening. and what is 'Class' class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = Class.new
```

This is similar to:

```
class A
end
```

As you are defining an empty class and giving it the name `A`. (NB: In Ruby the convention is that identifiers starting with a capital letter are constants.)

```
class << A
  def speak
    puts "Dave"
  end
end
```

is similar to:

```
class A
  def A.speak
    puts "Dave"
  end
end
```

Here you are defining a class method on `A` (as opposed to an instance method).

The line:

```
A.speak
```

is simply calling the class method.

Finally:

```
B = A.new
```

is creating an instance of class `A` and assigning it to the constant `B`.

---

To answer your other question. The class of `Class` is... `Class`! You can see this in `irb`:

```
irb(main):022:0> Class.class
=> Class
```

Comment: So what is A ? an Object or a class ?

Comment: In Ruby classes are also objects. So it is both.

Comment: Jergason is correct. `A` is a class, you can also say it is an object whose class is `Class`, or that it is an instance of class `Class`. It is not an instance of the class `A`, but `B` is an instance of class `A`. Furthermore, `B` itself is not a class, but it is an object.

Comment: Awesome thanks ...So many doubts cleared today. 
Ruby is truly object oriented.

Comment: @fd But class 'Class' is an instance on class 'Class'

Comment: What i understand from above is in stark contrast to my understanding of classical OOP. So to get it straight, we are creating objects from objects am i right ?

Comment: @pankajfoharey Yes. All classes are instances of class `Class` by definition. Since `Class` is itself a class, it follows it should also be an instance of `Class`. Hope that doesn't sound too circular :)

Comment: @pankajfoharey Be careful, it is not a strict equivalence. You wouldn't normally expect to create an object from *any* object in Ruby. Just those objects that are classes. For example, `B.new` above would give an error, because `B` is not a class.